# How do I center this div on the div before?

Tags: html, css

I can´t center the .login-form div over the .bg-opacity div. I´ve tried by myself in several ways.
This is my best attempt so far, I have tried also with the display:flex and neither worked.
All I get is the div with the dimensions I suggest in the template but at the start of the page instead of being in the middle.

I can guess it is all about the position attribute, I don't know that much about it yet so I will thank even more if someone could also explain how is it about.

```css
body {
  background-image: url(/src/background.PNG);
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
}

.bg-opacity {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(39, 39, 39, 0.96);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 10em 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 5em 1fr;
}

.login-form {
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  /*justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;*/
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-opacity">
  <div>
    <form action="" class="login-form">
      <input type="name" size="50px">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Position absolute is pretty much messing your entire css, you'd need to remove that and work around your positioning.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  background-image: url(/src/background.PNG);
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
}

.bg-opacity {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: cetner;
  background-color: rgba(39, 39, 39, 0.96);
}

.login-form-wrapper{
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
}

.login-form {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 15px;
}

input {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-opacity">
  <div class="login-form-wrapper">
    <form action="" class="login-form">
      <input type="name" size="50">
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```